# react navigation: deep linking with state persistence not working on the web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-native-web

I'm using react navigation v5 on the web and when I manually change the URL and refresh I am kept on the same screen instead of navigating to the new screen. I persisted my navigation state so that behavior is expected and every time the navigation state changes, it is set into local storage. When I manually change the url the navigation container does not know that I am trying to navigate thus returns me the previous navigation state. Below, the handlePushToScreen function was experimental and did not work. Does anyone know how to push a route on top when I manually change the url? Also, I've tried using the useLinkTo hook but I cannot use it since I'm outside of the navigation.

App.tsx

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePushToScreen = () => {
      const route = navigationRef.current?.getCurrentRoute();
      const pushAction = StackActions.push(route.name);

      const prevRoute = localStorage.getItem('prevRoute');

      if (prevRoute !== null && prevRoute !== window.location.pathname) {
        navigationRef?.current.dispatch(StackActions.push(route.name));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('prevRoute', window.location.pathname);
      }
    };

    if (isNavMounted) {
      handlePushToScreen();
    }
  }, [window.location.pathname, isNavMounted]);
 useEffect(() => {
    const restoreState = async () => {
      try {
        const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();

        const savedStateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);

        const state = savedStateString
          ? JSON.parse(savedStateString)
          : undefined;

        if (state !== undefined) {
        

          setInitialState(state);
        }
      } finally {
        setIsReady(true);
      }
    };
    if (!isReady) {
      restoreState();
    }
  }, [isReady]);

  const handleNavigationChange = (state) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state));
  };

  if (!isReady) {
    return <Text>loading stuff...</Text>;
  }
return (
   <NavigationContainer
          linking={linking}
          initialState={initialState}
          onReady={() => setIsNavMounted(true)}
          onStateChange={(state) => handleNavigationChange(state)}
          ref={navigationRef}
          fallback={<Text>Loading…</Text>}>
   <MainStackNavigator />
 </NavigationContainer>
);
```